# using a function from Page Object in Protractor

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

I have this code in my afterEach block that works to console log the page source for a failed spec. But I want to move it to another class instead.

```
    afterEach(function () {

    const state = this.currentTest.state;
    if (state === 'failed') {
        browser.driver.getPageSource().then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);     
        });
    }
});
```

but when i try to use the following in another class, i get 'Property 'currentTest' does not exist on type 'HelperClass'. How do i declare the currentTest property?

```
import { browser, } from 'protractor';
export class HelperClass {

    public getSource() {

        const state = this.currentTest.state;
        if (state === 'failed') {
            browser.driver.getPageSource().then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the `afterEach` hook comes from which package?  Jasmine, Allure, Cucumber or other?

Comment: it is using Mocha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

**test file:**

```
const helper = new HelperClass(); // create object for class
  afterEach(async ()=> {
    const state = this.currentTest.state;
    await helper.getSource(state);
});
```

**Class File**

```
import { browser, } from 'protractor';
export class HelperClass {

    public getSource(state:any) {

        if (state === 'failed') {
            browser.driver.getPageSource().then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are sending the `State` from your test file.
Hope it helps you

Comment: the above solution works, but i get warning: error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' for: this.currentTest.state;