# use this.currentTestState from helper class

Tags: protractor, mocha.js

I want to use `this.currentTest.state` from a helper class, and not in my test file. But i get `Property 'currentTest' does not exist on type HelperClass.`

What is the right way to use `this.currentTest.state` when in another class?

Helper Class:

```
export class HelperClass {

    public getSource() {
        const state = this.currentTest.state;
        if (state !== 'passed') {
            //  do this
        }
```

Test file:

```
afterEach(async () => {
    await helperClass.getSource();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer here for similar issue
 [using a function from Page Object in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008539/using-a-function-from-page-object-in-protractor/55015756#55015756)

The `state` value should be passed from your spec file.

Comment: so it cant be used from the helper class?

Comment: @user6086008 Mark the answer as correct if it resolved your issue. So that will help the others facing the similar issue.